# Typescript Error ';' expected

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I have no idea why I am getting these error. As far I have checked I don't think that the syntax are incorrect or something is missing. May be I am wrong. Please take a look at my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
coords:any;
accuracy:any;
error:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

watch(){
  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(resp) => {
    this.coords= resp.coords.latitude+' '+resp.coords.longitude;
    this.accuracy= resp.coords.accuracy+' '+'meters';
  }).catch((error)=>{
    this.error='Error getting location'+error;
  })
}

}
```

//These are the error log in brief:

```
Typescript Error
';' expected.

Typescript Error
Declaration or statement expected.

Typescript Error
'try' expected.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
watch(){
  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
  this.coords= resp.coords.latitude+' '+resp.coords.longitude;
  this.accuracy= resp.coords.accuracy+' '+'meters';
  }).catch((error)=>{
   this.error='Error getting location'+error;
  });
}
```

I guess you are missing a ";" after the catch and also a "(" after the then.

Comment: Use a compatible IDE such as VSCode so you don't have to spot the error manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
coords:any;
accuracy:any;
error:any;
```

coords could be changed to

```
coords: number
```

and then you would have typescript safety